# Haskell parsec prefix operator issue

Tags: haskell, parsec

I compile on Windows using GHC. Here is my code ([also available here](http://hpaste.org/86423)):

```
module GMC.GMLParser (parseGML) where

import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Expr
import Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Language
import qualified Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Token as P

type VarIdent = String
type FunIdent = String

data Expr =
      Var VarIdent
    | IntLit Integer
    | StringLit String
    | BiLit Bool
    | Op String Expr Expr
    | UnOp String Expr
    | Call FunIdent [Expr]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Stat =
      Seq [Stat]
    | Skip
    | Assign (Maybe VarIdent) Expr
    | If Expr Stat (Maybe Stat)
    deriving (Eq, Show)

lexer = P.makeTokenParser gmlDef

parens          = P.parens lexer    
braces          = P.braces lexer    
semi            = P.semi lexer
semiSep         = P.semiSep lexer  
semiSep1        = P.semiSep1 lexer    
commaSep        = P.commaSep lexer
commaSep1       = P.commaSep1 lexer
brackets        = P.brackets lexer
whiteSpace      = P.whiteSpace lexer    
symbol          = P.symbol lexer    
identifier      = P.identifier lexer    
reserved        = P.reserved lexer    
reservedOp      = P.reservedOp lexer
integer         = P.integer lexer    
charLiteral     = P.charLiteral lexer    
stringLiteral   = P.stringLiteral lexer


operators =
    [ [ prefix "-" ]
    , [ op "*"  AssocLeft, op "/"  AssocLeft ]
    , [ op "+"  AssocLeft, op "-"  AssocLeft ]
    , [ op "=" AssocNone, op "<>" AssocNone, op "<="  AssocNone
      , op "<" AssocNone, op ">="  AssocNone, op ">" AssocNone ]
    , [ op "&" AssocRight, op "&&" AssocRight ] -- Right for shortcircuiting
    , [ op "|" AssocRight, op "||" AssocRight ] -- Right for shortcircuiting
    , [ op ":=" AssocRight ]
    ]
    where
      op name assoc   = Infix (do{ reservedOp name
                                  ; return (\x y -> Op name x y) 
                                  }) assoc
      prefix name     = Prefix  (do{ reservedOp name
                                  ; return (\x -> UnOp name x)
                                  })


gmlDef :: LanguageDef st
gmlDef = emptyDef
    { commentStart    = "/*"
    , commentEnd      = "*/"
    , commentLine     = "//"
    , nestedComments  = True
    , identStart      = letter
    , identLetter     = alphaNum <|> oneOf "_"
    , reservedNames   = []
    , reservedOpNames = []
    , caseSensitive   = True
    }

parseGML :: String -> Either ParseError [Stat]
parseGML input = parse (whiteSpace >> many stat) "" input

intLit :: Parser Expr
intLit = IntLit <$> integer

strLit :: Parser Expr
strLit = StringLit <$> stringLiteral

variable :: Parser Expr
variable = do ident <- identifier
              memb <- optional $ symbol "." -- ignored for now, only parse its existance
              vname <- optional identifier -- ignored for now, only parse its existance
              indx <- optional $ brackets expr -- ignored for now, only parse its existance
              return (Var ident)

expr :: Parser Expr
expr = buildExpressionParser operators genExpr

genExpr :: Parser Expr
genExpr = choice [ intLit
                 , strLit
                 , try callExpr
                 , variable
                 , parens expr
                 ]

callExpr :: Parser Expr
callExpr = Call <$> identifier <*> parens (commaSep expr)

stat :: Parser Stat
stat =  do optional $ skipMany1 semi
           choice [ ifStat
                  , assignStat
                  , seqStat
                  ]

seqStat :: Parser Stat
seqStat = do stmts <- braces $ many stat
             return $ if null stmts then Skip else Seq stmts

ifStat :: Parser Stat
ifStat = If <$> (reserved "if" >> expr)
            <*> (optional (reserved "then") >> stat)
            <*> (optionMaybe $ reserved "else" >> stat)

assignStat :: Parser Stat
assignStat = do ident <- (optionMaybe $ try $ variable >> symbol "=")
                stmt <- case ident of
                    Just x -> expr
                    Nothing -> callExpr
                return (Assign ident stmt)
```

The problem in question is that parsing prefixed real numbers and variables give weird results.

`x=-3` gives `[Assign (Just "=") (UnOp "-" (IntLit 3))]` which is correct. More complex expressions like `x=5+-3` and `x = (arr[4]>-1 && 1)` however, seem to give incorrect results.

`x = arr[4]>-1` gives `[Assign (Just '=') (Var "arr")]` however should be `[Assign (Just "x") (Op ">" (Var "arr") (UnOp "-" (IntLit 1)))]`

`x=5+-3` strangely gives `[Assign (Just "=" (IntLit 5))` when it should be `[Assign (Just "x") (Op "+" (IntLit 5) (UnOp "-" (IntLit 3)))]`

I think its because of something to do with my operator precedence, or, that in general my implementation of the prefix `-` operator seems to be unreliable. I would greatly appreciate guidance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues:

```
ident <- (optionMaybe $ try $ variable >> symbol "=")
```

This is parsing and ignoring `variable`, then returning the result of `symbol "="`. Furthermore, `variable` would be a type error here. I'll use `identifier` instead for testing here, but you probably want something fancier.

```
parse (whiteSpace >> many stat) "" input
```

Your test inputs suggest that you intend the whole thing to be parsed. You should probably eat whitespace at the end and then use `eof` to make sure it consumes the entire input.

Finally, on the input `"x = arr[4]>-1"` I'm pretty sure the lexer considers `>-` a single token, as does Haskell's own grammar. So in this case the parser was correct (and will give an error if you add the `eof` I suggested). Note that this does *not* occur with the assignment statements because that's not being parsed by Parsec's expression parser.

Here's the output I get after making those changes (please excuse my weird GHCi prompt):

```
∀x. x ⊢ parseGML "x=-3"
Right [Assign (Just "x") (UnOp "-" (IntLit 3))]
∀x. x ⊢ parseGML "x = arr[4]>-1"
Left (line 1, column 11):
unexpected '>'
expecting ";", "if", identifier, "{" or end of input
∀x. x ⊢ parseGML "x = arr[4]> -1"
Right [Assign (Just "x") (Op ">" (Var "arr") (UnOp "-" (IntLit 1)))]
∀x. x ⊢ parseGML "x = 5+-3"
Left (line 1, column 6):
unexpected '+'
expecting ";", "if", identifier, "{" or end of input
∀x. x ⊢ parseGML "x = 5+ -3"
Right [Assign (Just "x") (Op "+" (IntLit 5) (UnOp "-" (IntLit 3)))]
∀x. x ⊢
```

Comment: Is it possible to convince the expression parser that >- isn't an operator?

Comment: @kvanberendonck: Possibly. I'm not terribly familiar with it, though.

Comment: It's a bit off topic, but I love the prompt! Where can I find out what it means? I guess it has something to do with logic?

Comment: @ocharles: The `⊢` means "proves that" or "therefore", sort of a meta-implication. It's called a [turnstile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turnstile_%28symbol%29). The `∀x. x` is "forall x, x", which is the most general type of `undefined` and only true/an inhabited type in an inconsistent logic/Turing-complete language. To quote roconnor on IRC, "cmccann is saying that if everything is inhabited, then whatever nonsense he is about to write follows." Look up "Curry-Howard correspondence" if you don't know what logic has to do with types. :]

Answer (score 3):

Your line 128:

```
assignStat = do ident <- (optionMaybe $ try $ variable >> symbol "=")
```

I want to focus on this bit:

```
variable >> symbol "="
```

What this does:

- parses a variable, throwing away the parse result
- parses a `=` token
- returns the result of parsing the `=` as the result of the overall parse

What you want to happen instead:

- parse a variable
- parse a `=` token, throwing away the parse result
- return the result of parsing the variable as the result of the overall parse

What to change that snippet of code to:

```
variable <* symbol "="
```

(and you'll need to import `(<*)` from Control.Applicative)

Except it's not that simple: the expressions have these types:

```
variable >> symbol "=" :: Parser String
variable <* symbol "=" :: Parser Expr
```

You'll have to work out for yourself whether `variable` is really the right parser to call at this point, or whether the first field of the `Align` constructor should instead be a `Maybe Expr`, or whether you should fix it some other way.